Replacing Blank KPI Tooltips with '0' or 'N/A' for Missing data
To meet the client's requirement in Tableau, we need to replace blanks in KPI tooltips with "0" or "N/A" when no data exists in Salesforce (not even null values). We’ve tried using ZN and ISNULL, but they don’t work without records. Manually adding values for missing months didn’t work either. Is there another solution, or is this not possible?
We are expecting a way to display '0' or 'N/A' in place of blank on the dashboard , when there is no data entry for that particular row.

You're looking for the IFNULL function; where an expression or field is returned if there is a value, otherwise, if its null, it will return an expression of your choice, so long as the data types are valid.
IFNULL([Month], 0)
IFNULL([Month], 'N/A')

For more examples and further explanation, see the IFNULL Function Documentation from Tableau.
